# Python throws Attribute Error for base class method in inherited class

Tags: python, function, methods, iteration, attributeerror

I'm getting Attribute error as below while calling `BaseSocketDataHandler` class function by getting string from key name as string and converting it to method name with `self.method_name = getattr(self, "self.__process_" + key.lower().replace(" ", "_"))` while iterating `info_dict_map`

> AttributeError: 'DataHandler' object has no attribute
>   'self.__process_info'

I don't get why I am getting this error. Is it proper way to call an function by string, or I should do something else?

```
class BaseSocketDataHandler(object):
    def __init__(self, sql_address, sql_user, sql_pswd, sql_db_name):
        .....
        self.db_connector = MySqlConnector(address=sql_address, suser=sql_user, spwd=sql_pswd, db_name=sql_db_name)
        .....
        self.info_dict = dict()
        self.info_dict_map = {"date_time": (0, 12), "info_len": (12, 13), "info": (13, 14), "reserved": (36, 37)}
        self.hex_data_dict = {"data_content": "0123456789abcdef10111213141516171819"

    @staticmethod
    def __convert_to_int(data):
        return int(data, 16)

    @staticmethod
    def __process_reserved(data):
        return data

    def __process_date_time(self, date_time_in_hex):
        date_time = tuple()
        for x in date_time_in_hex:
            date_time += self.__convert_to_int(x)
        return date_time

    def __process_info_len(self, info_len):
        return self.__convert_to_int(info_len)

    def __process_info(self, info):
        return self.__convert_to_int(number_of_sat)

    def make_info(self):
        for key, val in self.info_dict_map.items():
            method_name = getattr(self, "self.__process_" + key.lower().replace(" ", "_"))
            key_var = key
            setattr(self, key_var, method_name(self.hex_data_dict["data_content"][val[0]: val[1]]))
            self._info_dict.update({key: key_var})
            self.method_name = None




class DataHandler(BaseSocketDataHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DataHandler, self).__init__(sql_address, sql_user, sql_pswd, sql_db_name)

    def run_forever(self):
        while True:
            try:
                self.make_info()
            except Exception as uee:
                self.log.exception(self._log_msg(uee))
                break
```

Comment: [Private Variables and Class-local References](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because "process" is preceded by two underscores. This is called name mangling. From the python documentation:

> Since there is a valid use-case for class-private members (namely to
>   avoid name clashes of names with names defined by subclasses), there
>   is limited support for such a mechanism, called name mangling. **Any
>   identifier of the form __spam (at least two leading underscores, at
>   most one trailing underscore)** is textually replaced with
>   _classname__spam, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. This mangling is done without regard
>   to the syntactic position of the identifier, as long as it occurs
>   within the definition of a class.